How to make fdupes or jdupes skip remaining files in a folder after finding one duplicate in it?
I’ve got 50+ duplicated folders scattered deep inside a tree, with 3,000~12,000 files each, I’d like to purge.
jdupes takes a lot of time (even using -QT optimizations), since every one of the thousands of files in those folders is a duplicate.
In this scenario, it’d be enough if jdupes/fdupes printed any folders where at least one dupe was found, and skipped comparing the remaining files in these folders. I could then manually inspect the folders and delete all files much quicker.
Any way to achieve such behavior, maybe with a script or some other way?
